# EventEmiiter memory leak when automigrating models in loopback

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopbackjs

isActual() seems to add listener for every model you call it against meaning that when you have more than 10, you get the EventEmiiter memory leak detected.

- Is there a best practice relating to automigrations?
- Are these listeners temporary? (Could be ignored by setMaxListeners() safely)

Otherwise, seems like it would possibly be better to run migration outside of the node app, I currently run it as part of the boot process.

Here is my code, in server/boot/:

```
function autoMigrateAll(){
    var path = require('path');
    var models = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../model-config.json'));
    Object.keys(models).forEach(function(key) {
      app.dataSources.db.isActual(key, function(err, actual) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!actual) {
          app.dataSources.db.automigrate(key, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Model ' + key + ' migrated');
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Not sure if relevant, since it could be related to connector code, I am using mysql.

Comment: Why you havent checked it? `emitter.listenerCount()` ?

Comment: its one listener per model, at this time I am at 15 but should keep growing. I am wondering (maybe unclear?) if those listeners have impact during the app operation (this max listener defaulting to 10 has a reason for being I assume)